# Is it bad karma to make fake reviews?

Tags: karma, jiva

I am a freelancer just starting out, I know if I get fake reviews on my profile, my freelancing career will boost and I will get lots of work.
I want to know if it is bad karma to get fake reviews?
If yes, could you quote something that our scriptures have to say in that direction?
Thank you very much

Comment: Please see forum rules. Personal advice is not allowed. Do you think that dharma allows or condones lies and untruth??

Comment: It is not possible to answer such a personal question. Answer will be opinionated. Ig no if you serve your customers like someone who would have actually earned those reviews would have. If it leads to some gain on the side of customers so it shouldn't be bad

Answer (score 1):

If you are not harming anyone with your fake reviews on your own account then it is not a sin. Also, I hope you will reach up to the mark if you get any new assignment because of your fake reviews.

Har Har Maha Dev!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is an ethical question. In Ethics, it is very hard to define what is good and bad. To see all the issues in the field of Ethics and clarifying what is ethical, please read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethics. In particular you are asking the question pertaining to the Professional Ethics. Read more about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professional_ethics. Scriptures will only give you high level answers/guidelines. You will not find answer to your exact question in the scriptures. Naively speaking, anyone would be able to tell you that - posting fake reviews is not a good thing. As far as the bad karma is concerned, you would have to examine: your ultimate motive, greatest good of greatest number, potential harm to someone, state of your inner conscience etc. A contradictory example: Arjuna got to haven even after killing many people! Another example: Sage Kaushika and his vows to Speaking the Truth (Read 6th paragraph from top in blue color: https://www.sriramchandra.in/SeminarArchives/Truthfulness/Meghana.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Karma is Karma, it doesn't operate on good vs bad, or right vs wrong as they are all polarities based on situation/circumstance and human opinion. Karma simply means Action, and its outcome automatically tags along. In your case the outcome can be anything, we can't put a pin as to what will happen, whom it will damage, whom it will cause harm and who will benefit. Your current expectations are limited to the information crunched by your intellect. The number of combinations it can crunch is also limited based on the variables it can comprehend. **So what is the Answer as per the scriptures?** this is your real question and its a very generic one, why? Because it doesn't just apply to you, it befalls on all entities in creation.

So, what is dharma? What is MY Dharma? Well, that will change based on the person, the person's situation, the social and geographic circumstances, time, and more. There is a beautiful story in Mahabharatam where Sri Krishna goes into a Yogic Slumber and witnesses a congregation heading towards him and the question that He asked was "What is Dharma". Each person gave an explanation based on their personal circumstance, their caliber to face them, and the understanding they reached with their knowledge. Sri Krishna evaluated each of them based on their answer.

What if I don't know my dharma nor do I have time and situation to explore? Well, use your own wisdom and your own conscience as your judge.